# Как отправить POST запрос через curl, используя функцию хрома Copy as cURL (cmd)?

Tags: curl, requests, https, bat

Отлавливаю запрос через chrome F12 => Network
Кликаю на запрос ПКМ, нажимаю Copy => Copy as cURL (cmd)
Получаю подобное:

```
curl 'https://account.mail.ru/api/v1/user/signup' \
  -H 'authority: account.mail.ru' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'x-request-id: ef1e213c-26a6-332d-bf1b-8be1a971f6fe' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'origin: https://account.mail.ru' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru&app_id_mytracker=58519' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie:' \
  --data-raw $'------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="extended"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="more_password_strength"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="context"\r\n\r\nsignup\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="browser"\r\n\r\n{"screen":{"availWidth":"1920","availHeight":"1040","width":"1920","height":"1080","colorDepth":"24","pixelDepth":"24","availLeft":"0","availTop":"0"},"navigator":{"vendorSub":"","productSub":"20030107","vendor":"Google Inc.","maxTouchPoints":"0","doNotTrack":"inaccessible","hardwareConcurrency":"8","cookieEnabled":"true","appCodeName":"Mozilla","appName":"Netscape","appVersion":"5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36","platform":"Win32","product":"Gecko","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36","language":"ru-RU","onLine":"true","webdriver":"false","pdfViewerEnabled":"true","deviceMemory":"8"},"flash":{"version":"inaccessible"}}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="from"\r\n\r\nmain\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_me_ads"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_me_ads_common"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\n{"first":"imechko","last":"famochka"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="birthday"\r\n\r\n{"day":3,"month":6,"year":1992}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="sex"\r\n\r\nfemale\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="login"\r\n\r\nfamochka\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="domain"\r\n\r\ninbox.ru\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="password"\r\n\r\n111zzz111zzz=\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="restore"\r\n\r\n{"secret":"-","secret_answer":"-","additional_email":"ardacan54524@gmail.com"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="htmlencoded"\r\n\r\nfalse\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="utm"\r\n\r\n{}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPQdK1qxMovrr8yGQ--\r\n' \
  --compressed
```

Но это не работает, если записать этот код в start.bat, положить в одну директорию с curl.exe и запустить батник. Батник зачем то начинает построчно выполнять этот код. Как правильно использовать этот код с cURL?

Comment: Ну перенос строк тут явно линуксовый, а `батник` - явно из мира винды. Я бы начал копать отсюда.